# Filter performance on objects array

Tags: javascript, performance, object, optimization, filter

If I have a an array of objects called `filteredList` and a function such as :

```
function    buildList(filteredList, p1, p2, p3) {
    var resultList = [];

    for (var i =0; i < filteredList.length; i++) {
        if (filteredList[i].type === 'global' && filteredList[i].p1 === p1 && filteredList[i].p2 === p2 && filteredList[i].p3 === p3)
            resultList.push(filteredList[i]);
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

What would be the performance difference if instead of looping through my array like I do, I would do something like : `filteredList.filter(rebuildList)`

`rebuildList` being a function checking the same conditions than `buildList`

Would it do the same ? (Looping through each element)

Can you think of a more optimized and efficient way to do it ? I'm calling a function like `buildList` many times in my project and it consumes a great amount of time.

Comment: What is `filteredList`? It is a `array` or `object`. It is an object then performance will be fasted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. Example coming soon

Regarding performance you should read here: [Fastest way to find an item in a JavaScript Array](http://www.andygup.net/fastest-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array/)

Comment: That's what I'm thinking to do, but my question is what will the performance impact be ? Would it do the same : looping through each element, or doest it do something more efficient ? If so, what ?

Comment: I didn't reallly get what are the seek and Object approach in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/agup/Y8SBL/10/ They seem to be the more efficient but I don't know how to apply them to my case.

It looks like the seeek approach is the use of `indexOf` but in my case I have objects so I can't do it unless I `JSON.stringify` it and it might be even more time consuming to do so

Comment: It looks like this article isn't trustable : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459395/why-using-for-is-faster-than-some-or-filter

Comment: That article is for finding a single item, not filtering a list....